# Отображение блоков при смене табов

Tags: angular, angular4, tabs

Создаю панель с табами, где каждая панель имеет общий блок `header`. Как сделать, чтобы содержимое `block1`, `block2`, `block3` зависело от выбранного таба? Если выбран таб first должны отображаться блоки header и block1, если таб second - блоки header и block2 и по третьему табу аналогично. Не совсем понятно что должен в себе содержать метод `changeTabs()`

```js
  public isBlock1 = true;
  public isBlock2 = false;
  public isBlock3 = false;
  
  changeTabs(event):void {
      isBlock1 != isBlock1; 
  }
```

```html
        <mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="changeTabs($event)">
            <mat-tab label="first"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="second"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="third"></mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="header">Header</div>
            <div *ngIf="isBlock2! && !isBlock3" class="block1">Text</div>
            <div *ngIf="isBlock1! && !isBlock3" class="block2">Text</div>
            <div *ngIf="isBlock1! && !isBlock2" class="block3">Text</div>
          </div>
```

Comment: вопрос непонятен

Comment: @overthesanity, не работает отображение по *ngIf. Если выбран таб `first` должны отображаться блоки `header` и  `block1`, если таб `second` - блоки `header` и `block2` и по третьему табу аналогично

Comment: у `mat-tab-group` есть событие `selectedTabChange`, его нужно слушать, проверять какой таб выбрали и показывать нужный блок

Comment: @overthesanity, дополнила вопрос. не совсем понятно, что должен содержать в себе метод `changeTabs(). если с двумя табами понятно как делать, то как проверять три не совсем

Comment: а зачем вам отдельные блоки если можно все внутрь `mat-tab` засунуть?

Comment: @overthesanity можно, но `header` достаточно большой блок, и дублирование кода в каждом табе плохой вариант

Comment: зачем дублировать, хедер можно вынести в ng-template и проджектить в каждом блоке через ngTemplateOutlet

Comment: @overthesanity, можете привести пример? пробую делать таким способом, не взлетает

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#example